# Chaining getting a class name to creating the class and calling a method?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out if this is a logic issue on my part or just a lack of knowledge.

I have a static method `ConnectionFactory::getConnectionInterface($config['type'])`, which returns a string, a class name. That class has a method on it, `createConnection`. I'm trying to figure out if I can do it all in one line or not. I tried various things like

```
new {ConnectionFactory::getConnectionInterface($config['type'])}()->createConnection();
```

Switching the `{}` for `()`, adding them around the whole new, etc. I feel like I get closer in some parts, further in others.

I know I could just have the factory return a new instance of the object (and from my understanding, that may be the right way to do it?), but I'm hoping to figure out how I can write this code, or if I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the new object in `()`

```
(new ConnectionFactory::getConnectionInterface($config['type'])())->createConnection();
```

Alternatively you could return an instance of the class instead of the class name.

```
public static function getConnectionInterface($type) {
    // generate class name $class

    return new $class()
}
```

Then use just use that object instead of creating a new instance when you call it.

```
$connection = ConnectionFactory::getConnectionInterface($config['type'])->createConnection()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I tried this (even copied what you have above), but I get `syntax error, unexpected 'getConnectionInterface' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'` when I do. And I do suspect I should be generating it in my factory (I imagine this is the correct use of a factory pattern?), I just figured knowing how to do it would be useful.